# Why Getting duplicate number while using select count(*)?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count/group the number of terminal_id store on my database, but I observed that same number is counted twice.
I run the script below

```
SELECT terminal_id, count(*) AS 'count' from tbl_request_1 GROUP BY terminal_id
```

and the result is

```
terminal_id  count
10331317       3
10331349       1
10331368       2
10331377       1
10331901       3
10331901       1
10331902       2
10331904       2
10331905       5
10331905       1
```

I have 10331905 and 10331901 counted twice however, 10331901 suppose to be 4 and 10331905 suppose to be 6.
Note: the data on my db are well formated.

[My phpMyAdmin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHWCo.jpg) 
Kindly help

Comment: not  possible, unless terminal_id isn't a number, e.g. it's a string and there's whitespace causing each of those numbers to be unique, even though they LOOK like dupes.

Comment: 'count' its quotes or backticks? ??? well maybe u have empty space in your column value.

Comment: You can see in the screenshot there appears to be a \r | \n on the end of the value, add length(terminal_id) to the select group to confirm

Comment: test it: SELECT TRIM(terminal_id), COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tbl_request_1
GROUP BY TRIM(terminal_id)

Comment: @MarcB, I copied one of the number and replace it in db again the result was same. there is no WHITESPACE in the column.

Comment: @devpro, thanks for your code, however, the result still the SAME.

Comment: cool, and what is the data type of ?? and how many records available against this id? 10331905?? `SELECT count(*) FROM table where terminal_id = 10331905`?? test it

Comment: @Oladeji: what is the type of the filed? if it's **NOT** int, then you have whitespace in there.cutting/pasting is pointless, since you'd be cutting/pasting that whitespace as well. add `length(terminal_id)` into your query. you'll see that the "dupe" numbers have different lengths. Which then begs the question of why you're storing a numerical value in a text-type field. That's plain bad design.

Comment: @devpro, I use varchar as datatype, but I change it to int now and its very FINE!. Thanks so much

Comment: good work, and forget what @MarcB mentioned in his comments.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `terminal_id` is not an integer. There would be some spaces in it.

Comment: terminal_id are all integer, I copied one 10331905 and paste it to other column with same number, yet the result still the same!

Comment: Thanks @jr_dev, I've change the data type to int and its fine now!

Comment: you are saying theat u tried querying select with column for .eg 10331905 still same...now this is strange indeed..